# composite primary key and unique key as a foreign key

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, normalization, composite

Ok Here is the situation.

- A university has more than one faculty.
- Each faculty has more than one department.

I do not want any duplicated faculty or department. So I defined the three tables below.

```
CREATE TABLE university (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    long_name VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    country VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
) Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE school_faculty (
    id INT UNIQUE NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(45),
    universityID INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (name, universityID),
    FOREIGN KEY (universityID) REFERENCES university (id)
) Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE department (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    schoolfacultyID INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (schoolfacultyID)
        REFERENCES school_faculty (id)
) Engine=InnoDB;
```

Please tell me if it's wrong or if there is a better way. I am struggling with it and kinda helpless.

Comment: That seems correct so far based on the two bullet points at the beginning of your post.

Comment: Proper [sample code](http://sscce.org/) (here, SQL statements) is more useful than any ad hoc schema and sample data format. Please use `CREATE TABLE` for your samples.

Comment: updated: table structure attached

Comment: @stanchen: pictures are also next to useless when it comes to sample code, as they can't be copied and pasted for testing. Read the link in my previous comment for more and please use SQL statements, as mentioned.

Comment: As other members (below & above) pointed out, I am now very confident in my structure and am able to make things work as I expected. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks ok.

You could normalize things a little more by having a table of just falculty/department names and convert your department/falculty tables to be (universityID, facultyNameID). But that level of normalization is probably overkill. While it's highly likely there's more that one Physics or Basket Weaving faculty in all the universities, the few extra bytes you'd use by keeping multiple copies of the word "Physics" in the table is not going to break the bank.

The same applies to the departments, and the same "probably not a problem" as well.

Comment: i dun want the faculty or department duplicated. I dun get why it's not good to have a table where auto-increase unique key is a primary key, and the other two columns as a composite primary key. (in this case, Faculty Table)

Comment: it's called a surrogate key. It's easier to haul around that one single ID field rather than having to drag around the full university/faculty/department key set, especially when you're going to using these department ID as foreign keys elsewhere.

Comment: I agree! That's my point having surrogate key. I just updated the original post with the table structure image. So according to my design, is it properly structured? Any better way?

Comment: Moving faculty/department names to another table and changing the tables to use "IDs" for those things instead has absolutely nothing to do with normalization. Unfortunately there's a common misconception that it does and that normalization means moving some attribute to a new table and replacing it with a foreign key. Since Marc brought it up as an example of normalization I thought it worth pointing that out.

Answer (score -1):

You are fine except for the `school_faculty` table. It would be better to use the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE school_faculty (
    id PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(45),
    universityID INT,
    UNIQUE (name, universityID),
    FOREIGN KEY (universityID) REFERENCES university (id)
) Engine=InnoDB;
```

It is better to use an integer column as the PK instead of a composite key. In InnoDB tables, PK is a [clustered index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-index-types.html), so using the smallest data type for the PK means MySQL can read more data from index per scan. It is better in most cases for the primary key to be auto incrementing, which allows for easy ordering (they are basically already ordered).

Additionally, secondary (non-clustered) indexes store the data from the PK. Using a smaller type means secondary indexes take up less space. Any query that uses a secondary index must use the PK to access the actual row data and so will benefit from anything that improves access time via the PK.

You should also add a unique key on department (name, schoolfacultyID) to prevent duplicate departments in a given faculty.

Hope it helps.

Comment: if i do so, it would not allow different faculty_name with the same university_id.

Comment: This is a bad design. You could have a department assigned to a faculty which is in a completely different university than the stated university.

Comment: @stanchen: not so, since the unique index on school_faculty (name, universityID) is composite.

Comment: @MarcB: I'm not seeing how. I've updated ravnur's answer (as I understood it) to use SQL rather than his non-standard format. Did you interpret his answer differently?

Comment: @outis: with the original design, it could've allowed a department name pointing at something that belongs to "UofX" and a faculty ID that points of "UofY".

Comment: @MarcB: I still don't see that as possible. A department doesn't refer to a university; only faculties do that. From my understanding, the orginal design is the same as the current; only the language used to describe it has changed. ravnur's point was to make `id` the primary key, and create a unique key for the faculty name & university id.